# Android programming (how to display a string in a textview)

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi all. I'm working on an app that scans the devices system info and I was wondering if it was possible to add two strings:

- `String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;`
- `String model = Build.MODEL;`

to my `MainActivity` and display them on the screen somehow. Here is my `MainActivity`:

```
package com.shadycorp.diji.clock

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layour `activity_main` add two `TextView`s with assigned IDs:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/manufacturer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/model"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left" />
```

Then, in your `onCreate()` method, after inflating the layout, find these `TextView`s using assigned IDs:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
TextView manufacturerTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.manufacturer);
TextView modelTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.model);
// Now you can set TextView's text using setText() method:
manufacturerTextView.setText(Build.MANUFACTURER);
modelTextView.setText(Build.MODEL);
```

That's all!

Comment: Have you written anything before in Java? I guess not. Your code is incorrect. Post your layout XML file contents to pastebin.

Comment: I don't think so, since your code in syntactically incorrect. Here is corrected version: http://pastebin.com/zj243sEP

Answer (score 1):

First step, in your onCreate method, get a reference to your TextView component (using the resource name in XML), then you can set the text on it directly (last 2 lines in this code example show you what you need to do).

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_textview_resource_name);
    tv.setText("Text is: " + Build.MANUFACTURER + Build.MODEL);
}
```

Comment: how can i add the strings and then send them to a text view because im not entireely understanding the answers

Comment: Hmmm, not sure - there are 2 answers that show you exactly how to do it.  Find your UI resource, get a handle to it, and setText on it.  Either mine, or andr's answers are clear IMHO.

Comment: and now its saying build can not be resolved as a variable and the same for SavedInstanceState

Comment: You have a build error (syntax error somewhere).  Look in your XML files - and in your "Problems" tab on the bottom of your IDE (if it's eclipse)

Comment: @user1934637 please accept an answer which you feel helped you the most. By doing that you help others who stumble upon a similar problem in picking a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
textView.setText("Manufacturer " + manufacturer  + "Model" +model);
```